# AppFabric How Can I Create New Cache

Tags: appfabric-cache

Question very simple,

How can I create new cache with using c#. I didn't find any way using client api. Is there a easy way or is powershell using must.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current version it is not possible to create a new cache by using C#, you have to do it with PowerShell.